# 'character cinfo(300)*100 is mapped to character cinfo(300,100)' when building with gfortran

Tags: unix, fortran

I am trying to configure a program with a python visitations component. I am able to install the software, but when I re-run the configure option with the python flag --pysaleplot and then run make I get the following error.

```
Making all in pySALEPlot
Making all in src
updatevars: "character cinfo(300)*100" is mapped to "character cinfo(300,100)"

error: Command "/opt/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -I/tmp/tmpO0aK8p/src.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7 -    I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -
I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c -c readdatfile.F90 -o /tmp/tmpO0aK8p/readdatfile.o" failed with exit status 1
make[3]: *** [all-local] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is this a problem with the Fortran compiler that I am using?

Comment: Find some log file. Show the complete output. The actual problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: The log file that is generated seems to be during the configure phase which runs fine, but not during the make phase where the problem occurs.